# Ambiguity between overloaded constructors

Tags: c++, templates

Can someone please explain to me why in the following code I get an ambiguous call to the overloaded constructors in Foo if I attempt to instantiate MyFooC? My assumption was that the integer used as a constructor parameter would have been promoted to an unsigned int and been resolved but this is obviously incorrect.

```
template <typename t> class Foo
{
private:
    t m_Value;
    unsigned int m_Length;

public:
    Foo(const t& Value) :
        m_Value(Value),
        m_Length(0)
    {
    }

    Foo(unsigned int Length) :
        m_Value(static_cast<t>(0)),
        m_Length(Length)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
Foo<double> MyFooA(32U);
Foo<double> MyFooB(32.0f);
//Foo<double> MyFooC(32);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `int` can be converted to both a `double` and an `unsigned`; both are
considered "widening" conversions, and have equal rank.  As a general
rule, any time you overload, and one of the overloads is an integral
type, it's a good idea to overload on `int` as well, to be sure of
getting what you want, and avoiding ambiguities, when someone tries to
pass an integral constant.

BTW: although it is clear in context what you mean, in the C++ standard,
"promotion" has a very precise meaning, and does not include a
conversion of `int` to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the problem is that an int could just as easily be converted to a double.  I know of no specifications in C++ that dictates an order of preference for implicit casting, so when the compiler sees an int that could go to double or unsigned int, it views the call as ambiguous.

Comment: "Promotions" are preferred to "conversions", so given a `char`, a function taking `int` will be preferred to one taking `double`.  But the C++ standard uses a very limiting definition of "promotion"; basically, a promotion is a conversion which will take place in a binary operator where both operands have the same type.  (For example, if you add two `short`, both are promoted to `int` before the addition.)